# How can I use evil-mc in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/how-can-i-use-multiple-cursors-in-evil-spacemacs) is a semantically similar question but the OP's intent was more about which implementation of multiple cursors was "best".

I echo one of the commenters of that question who asked "Can you explain how to use it? I'm superconfused". . . as am I!  That answer included a list of keybindings (which are also available (though not in handy table format) on the `evil-mc` [readme](https://github.com/gabesoft/evil-mc)).  When I search on the web for this I get [keybindings](https://github.com/Ben-PH/spacemacs-cheatsheet) and [others with the same question](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacemacs/comments/4641zt/how_the_heck_do_i_use_multicursor_support/) but have not found just basic instructions.

Could someone just walk through an example of *how to use multiple cursors*?  For example, let's say I have this list of variables cut from a spec (including non-alignment):

```
 `purpose`   
   `dtlastmod` 
   `lastmod`   
   `dtrelver`  
   `relver`    
   `comps`
```

I want to change that list to:

```
 String purpose;
 String dtlastmod; 
 String lastmod;   
 String dtrelver;  
 String relver;
 String comps;
```

It *seems* like multiple cursors might make this easy but I'll be darned if I can't figure it out.  Is that a good use case?  If not, what is a good example and could you talk through the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pure evil-mc solution you need to have a cursor in each line. I don't know of such a function out of the box, but since this is the hackable editor I defined one:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-M-<") 'rno/evil-mc-make-cursors-for-all-regexp)
(evil-define-command rno/evil-mc-make-cursors-for-all-regexp ()
  "Initialize `evil-mc-pattern' and make cursors for all matches ignoring exact letter matches."
  :repeat ignore
  :evil-mc t
  (if (evil-mc-has-cursors-p) (user-error "Cursors already exist.")
    (setq evil-mc-pattern
          (cons (evil-ex-make-search-pattern (replace-regexp-in-string
                                              "\\w+"
                                              "\\w+"
                                              (buffer-substring-no-properties
                                               (region-beginning)
                                               (region-end))
                                              t
                                              'literal))
                nil))
    (evil-exit-visual-state)
    (evil-mc-make-cursors-for-all)
    (evil-mc-print-cursors-info "Created")))
```

How to use:

- make a visual selection of the first delimited term from backtick to backtick
- call the new function using `C-M-<` to create a cursor on each closing backtick

  - the function takes the selection and replaces all word characters (e.g. letters) by a regex matching all word characters, so it basically searches for two backticks with letters in between and creates cursors there
- `D` to delete the backtick and any other characters, e.g. trailing whitespace
- `a;ESC` to insert the semicolon at the end
- `` T` `` to move backwards before the next backtick
- `d0` to delete everything until the beginning of the line, e.g. leading whitespace
- `iString SPC ESC` to prepend "String "
- `g r q` to get rid of all fake cursors

Here is a short animation what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Pretty amazing, thanks for your insights! Fwitw for future readers, I had eventually figured some things out about multiple cursors and contributed those things to [this Spacemacs cheatsheet](https://github.com/Ben-PH/spacemacs-cheatsheet).

Answer (score 2):

For only affecting the six rows you could `narrow-to-region` using `SPC n r`

I'd break it down in the necessary steps:

- Remove leading whitespace using `SPC SPC delete-whitespace-rectangle RET`
- Remove trailing whitespace using `SPC x d w`
- Remove backticks using a series of commands, e.g.:

  - `v` on one backtick to create a visual selection
  - `g r m` to get a cursor for each instance of the selection
  - `x` to remove it
  - `g r q` to get rid of the cursors
- Prepending "String SPC"

  - `ggVG` to mark all lines in visual-line mode
  - `I` to jump the beginning of a line
  - `String`  to insert "String "
  - `ESC` to leave insert mode and have the insertion apply to all previously selected lines
- Appending ";"

  - `ggVG` to mark all lines in visual-line mode
  - `A` to jump the end of a line
  - `;` to insert the semicolon
  - `ESC` to leave insert mode and have the insertion apply to all previously selected lines

check out my other answer for a pure evil-mc solution